# json_encode add numbers to result?

Tags: php, json

I am having a very different question. For some reason, when the json_encode function receives a variable that has the value assigned by a multiplication, the `echo` result will be a different value than expected. Example:

```
<?php
  $test = 1.1 * 122;
  echo json_encode(array("test" => $test)); // prints {"test":134.20000000000002}
  echo $test; // prints 134.2
?>
```

For some reason, it doesn't work on every version of PHP, so I created a snippet on a tester that works:
[Online Tester](https://paiza.io/projects/ac19DwNBgn2oSqKa3fhW5A)

Why does this happen?

Comment: This is a [side effect of floating point math](https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/). Use `round()` if you need a specific precision.

Comment: Yes, but my question would be why this happens, since "122 * 1.1" doesn't give this value, would you know?

Answer (score -1):

Just use round function

```
  $test = round(1.1 * 122, 2);
  echo json_encode(array("test" => $test));
```

Comment: Yes, but my question would be why this happens, since 122 * 1.1 doesn't give this value, would you know?